# Hyperlink to another page is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I click on `Add to cart` hyperlink, cart.php page is not responding (it's not echoing the add variable. Hyperlink looks fine. However, there is something wrong in cart.php. Any response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ISBN']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['publisher']; ?></td>
        <td> <a href="cart.php?add=abc">Add to cart</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ISBN']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

cart.php page:

```
<?php
//
session_start();

$page  = 'search.php';
$lpage = 'cart.php';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cheapbook') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {

    echo $_GET['add'];
    $pieces   = explode(":", $_GET['add']);
    $quantity = mysqli_query('SELECT ISBN, title from book WHERE ISBN=$pieces[0]');
    $result   = mysqli_query($db, $quantity);
    while ($quantity_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['cart_' . $_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['cart_' . $_GET['add']] += 1;
        }
    }

    if ($pieces[1] == 'SearchByBookTitle') {
        header('location:' . $page . 'SearchByBookTitle=' . $pieces[2]);
    }
    if ($pieces[1] == 'SearchByAuthor') {
        header('location:' . $page . 'SearchByAuthor=' . $pieces[2]);
        echo $pieces[1];
    } else {
        header('location:' . $lpage);
    }

}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_' . $_GET['remove']]--;
    header('location:' . $page);
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_' . $_GET['remove']]--;
    header('location:' . $page);
}

if (isset($_GET['cart'])) {
    cart();
}

function cart()
{
    foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'curt_') {
                $total  = 0;
                $id     = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name) - 5));
                $get    = mysql_query("SELECT ISBN, title, price FROM book where id='.$id.'");
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $get);
                while ($get_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                    echo $get_row['title'] . 'X' . $value . '@Dollar' . $get_row['price'] . '=' . $sub . '<a href="cart.php?remove=.$id.">[-]</a><a href="cart.php?add=.$id.">[+]</a><a href="cart.php?delete=.$id.">[Delete]</a>';
                }
                $total += $sub;
            }
        }
        if ($total == 0) {
            echo "Your cart is empty";
        } else {
            echo "Paypal button";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the page loading anything? Whats your actual code, `abc`can't be your value because there is no `:`. You also are open to SQL injections with this code. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Works fine here. Something else is wrong, obviously. Saved both your files, and when I click the `Add to cart` link, it takes me to `cart.php` where it echos out `abc`

Answer (score 0):

This query coded like this of course will not work as expected

```
$quantity = mysqli_query('SELECT ISBN, title 
                          from book 
                          WHERE ISBN=$pieces[0]');
```

You need a double quoted string to use variable expansion, it does not work in a single quoted string.

You also need to add single quotes around the text varibale parameter value

```
$quantity = mysqli_query("SELECT ISBN, title 
                          from book 
                          WHERE ISBN='$pieces[0]'");
```

In future you would be well advised to add some error checking code after you attempt to execute a query and also use prepared and parameterised queries to avoid SQL Injection

```
$sql = "SELECT ISBN, title from book WHERE ISBN=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
if ( ! $stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pieces[0] );
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Riggs! It was silly mistake. I am Rookie in php